# Counting occurance of a specific number in an integer in C

Tags: c, count, integer

I'm having some troubles... I'm trying to input a number, followed by an integer of multiple numbers. I am trying to count how many times the first number occurs in the integer.
Now, I made this really easy code to show you what I actually am trying to do. The thing is, this code only compares two integers and tells me if they are the same or not. Mind you, I am very unexperienced in C programming, hence this question...

```
int main(){

    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;
    int count = 0;

    scanf("%d", &numberOne);
    scanf("%d", &numberTwo);

    if(numberOne == numberTwo){
        count++;
    }

    printf("Amount of equals found: %d", count);

return 0;
}
```

Now, if I'd have the following input: '1 1021023234', the output would be: 'Amount of equals found:0'
The output should be (in this case) 'The output would be Amount of equals found:2'

I hope you guys can give me some tips.

Comment: Why are you reading them as integers if you want to process the individual characters? Read them as a string.

Comment: I thought about doing that and tried it, but it didn't quite work out so well. I can't seem to find any tutorials on doing this.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on using `scanf`.

Comment: @user3426706 From the answer you selected as the best I did not understand what you actually need.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly then you need the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int numberOne;
    unsigned int numberTwo;
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int base;
    size_t n;

    printf( "Enter first number: " );
    scanf( "%u", &numberOne );

    printf( "Enter second number: " );
    scanf( "%u", &numberTwo );

    x = numberOne;
    base = 1;
    do { base *= 10; } while ( x /= 10 );

    n = 0;

    do { n += numberOne == numberTwo % base; } while ( numberTwo /= 10 );

    printf( "Amount of equals found: %u", n );

    return 0;
}
```

For numbers `12` and `76512612` the output is

```
Amount of equals found: 2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed what I ment!

Answer (score 0):

Write the code yourself. Here are the hints:

Since you need only one input,eliminate `numbertwo` from your program and implement the following:

1. `numberone%10` would give the first digit of the user input. Assign it to a variable `one`.
2. If user input(`numberone`)<10 , print `first digit is found 1 time in input` and exit the program.
3. Use a `while` loop and put `numberone>=10` in its condition.check `if(numberone%10==one)`  in the loop if true,increment variable `count`. Add 
   `numberone/10` after it.
4. Print your last `printf` and end the program

Comment: Thanks for the tips. This made me understand it better!

Answer (score 0):

you can read them as integer but you cannot compare them the way you are doing. to compare them you need to extract each digit from the number and compare.

```
temp = numbertwo % 10; //this gives the digit in the unit place
if(temp == numberone)
    count++;
numbertwo = numbertwo / 10; //this now removes the last digit that has already been compared
```

keep the above code in a loop until numbertwo becomes zero. and it will work as you wanted

another way to do this would be to read the integer as a String.

```
char* numbertwo;
char = malloc(20);
fgets(numbertwo, 20, stdin);
```

and then compare the integer in a for loop

Comment: Thanks! I'll do some experimenting with this.

Comment: Note the first example will not work with leading zeros, but that may be a moot point depending on the original problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using strings as below..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
char int1[100];
char int2[100];
int cnt=0;
scanf("%s",int1);
scanf("%s",int2);
char *p;
while(p=strstr(s1,s2))   //searches for the string s2 in s1 and if found, returns the address to the pointer p//
{
cnt++
s1=p+strlen(s2);   //now s1 points to the next location from the end of string s2 in s1//
}
printf("Amout of equals found:%d\n",cnt");
}
```